# How can I change key name with array_walk_recursive in an multidimensional Array

Tags: php

I can use array_walk_recursive function to modify some specific value, like this

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function (& $item, $key) {
    if($key === 'name') {
        $item = 'some value';
    }
});
```

But how can I modify the key name itself, it's not work with reference of $key. Help me please.

$arr here

```
$arr = [
  0 =>  [
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "1",
    "orderNumber" => 1,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => "balabala",
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 4,
    "children" => [
      0 => [
        "id" => 7,
        "name" => "departmentName_ProblemHere",
        "code" => "7",
        "orderNumber" => 7,
        "enabled" => true,
        "createSpace" => false,
        "description" => null,
        "lft" => 2,
        "lvl" => 1,
        "rgt" => 3,
        "children" => []
      ]
    ]
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => 2,
    "name" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "1",
    "orderNumber" => 2,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  2 => [
    "id" => 3,
    "name" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "1",
    "orderNumber" => 3,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  3 => [
    "id" => 4,
    "name" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "4",
    "orderNumber" => 4,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  4 => [
    "id" => 5,
    "name" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "5",
    "orderNumber" => 1,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  5 => [
    "id" => 6,
    "name" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "6",
    "orderNumber" => 6,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ]
];
```

May even be deeper, it's a dynamic tree.

The expected outcome like below, just change all "name" key to "text".

```
$arr = [
  0 =>  [
    "id" => 1,
    "text" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "1",
    "orderNumber" => 1,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => "balabala",
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 4,
    "children" => [
      0 => [
        "id" => 7,
        "text" => "departmentName_ProblemHere",
        "code" => "7",
        "orderNumber" => 7,
        "enabled" => true,
        "createSpace" => false,
        "description" => null,
        "lft" => 2,
        "lvl" => 1,
        "rgt" => 3,
        "children" => []
      ]
    ]
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => 2,
    "text" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "1",
    "orderNumber" => 2,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  2 => [
    "id" => 3,
    "text" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "1",
    "orderNumber" => 3,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  3 => [
    "id" => 4,
    "text" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "4",
    "orderNumber" => 4,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  4 => [
    "id" => 5,
    "text" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "5",
    "orderNumber" => 1,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ],
  5 => [
    "id" => 6,
    "text" => "departmentName",
    "code" => "6",
    "orderNumber" => 6,
    "enabled" => true,
    "createSpace" => false,
    "description" => null,
    "lft" => 1,
    "lvl" => 0,
    "rgt" => 2,
    "children" => []
  ]
];
```

Comment: You can't. Unset previous key and add a new one

Comment: @AlivetoDie and @u_mulder - but in array_walk_recursive `$arr[$key]` may not exists, as `$key` may be in any depth of array.

Comment: try `$item = NULL;`  like this:- https://eval.in/791116

Comment: @Justinas yep, you're right, that's the biggest problem actually. There's no solution to return a new array.

Comment: @TonyGao  in your case `array_walk_recursive()` become very lengthy. Need to see some other alternative. Please post expected outcome too. May be some-one can help based on expected outcome.